# what is the alternate for depreciation for XMLHttpRequest for file-saver?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filesaver.js

I am using [File Saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) for my react application to download files.

```
var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
..
..
..
FileSaver.saveAs(files['file_path'], files['file_title']);
```

It was working fine but few days back it showing an error now.

> **[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.**

Comment: Do you need to use File Saver? Are you downloading files from an external application?

Comment: yes i am downloading from s3

Answer (score 3):

This is showing because *FileSaver.js* [sets `async` parameter to `false`](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/src/FileSaver.js#L50) of [`XMLHttpRequest.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) when it uses the [`corsEnabled`](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/src/FileSaver.js#L47) method for the request and in your case it does because you are fetching data from a [different origin source](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/src/FileSaver.js#L96).

> **Note:** Synchronous requests on the main thread can be easily disruptive
>   to the user experience and should be avoided; in fact, many browsers
>   have deprecated synchronous XHR support on the main thread entirely.
>   Synchronous requests are permitted in [Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker).

If we look at the source, we'll see a comment that is being set to `false` to avoid popup blocker:

> ```js
> function corsEnabled (url) {
>   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
>   // use sync to avoid popup blocker
>   xhr.open('HEAD', url, false)
>   ...
> }
> ```

There is also an opened issue regarding this warning [Chrome gives me a warning in Angular app](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/574) with no responses at all.

I suggest that you just ignore this warning message until it is fixed. You can always fork the repo and remove that async `false` parameter from `xhr.open` call.

Comment: still it is showing same error and one more thing if i change this in package files and when package update it will again raise an issue.

Comment: @hu7sy you changed [`xhr.open('HEAD', url, false)`](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/src/FileSaver.js#L50) to `xhr.open('HEAD', url, true)` and it still shows the same error? The import in your application most likely fetches a compiled file, not the source file. You do not change it like this, I am stating in my answer that **you have to fork** the repo (*make the change and re-compile it*) and then use your fork to fetch the package inside `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the warning by invoking `saveAs` from a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
const FileSaver = require('file-saver');
..
..
..
new Promise(resolve => {
  resolve(FileSaver.saveAs(files['file_path'], files['file_title']));
})
.then(result => console.log("Done downloading") )
.catch(err => console.log("Error downloading: " + err));
```

Comment: didn't work for me but I upvoted anyway since it's a good thing to try and it was at -1